#  Where is the tell() function defined?

Tags: c++, macos, unix, gcc, file

Can you please tell me where the **off_t tell(int fd)** function is defined in **Mac OS X**? It's not in **fcntl.h** and not in **unistd.h**, where it is defined in **UNIX**... I can't use **ftell()** because the code I'm porting works with file descriptors.

I'm using GCC v4.2.1

Comment: Please don't [pseudotag] your question titles. That's what the tag list is for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use `lseek` instead, which offers the same functionality:

```
off_t tell(int fd)
{
    return lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: @Ryan: I don't see how that's relevant